# Use values from one javascript function into another

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need a little hand here, both this javascript functions are working properly, but I need a value from the first script, so I can "POST" it, but I can't figure out how to make the (string[3]) value to show on the second script and therefore use it.

The only function of this first script is to get values from the getsong.php file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var string[3]{
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
    ready: function () {
        var data = $.ajax({
          url: "getsong.php",
          async: false
         }).responseText;

         string = data.split('|');
        $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
            mp3: string[0]
        }).jPlayer("play");

        $('ol#one').html(string[1]);
        $('ol#two').html(string[2]);
        $('ol#three').html(string[3]);

    },
    ended: function (event) {  
        var data = $.ajax({
          url: "getsong.php",
          async: false
         }).responseText;

         string = data.split('|');
        $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
            mp3: string[0]
        }).jPlayer("play");


        $('ol#one').html(string[1]);
        $('ol#two').html(string[2]);
        $('ol#three').html(string[3]);

    },
    swfPath: "js",
    supplied: "mp3"

});
});
```

Then the only function is second script to post to the "update_db.php" with a value from (string[3]) from the script above, and also is reloading the page at the same time. I need the value in the 'STRING[3] GOES HERE' area.

```
$(function() {
$("#submit01").click(function() {
var song_id = $("#song_id").val();
var dataString = 'song_id='+ 'STRING[3] GOES HERE';

if(song_id=='')
{
$('.success').fadeOut(200).hide();
$('.error').fadeOut(200).show();
}
else
{
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "update_db.php",
data: dataString,
success: function timedRefresh(timeoutPeriod) {
setTimeout("location.reload(true);","0");
}
});
}
return false;
});
});


/////
}

</script>
```

Comment: You have a syntax error on the second line of your code `var string[3]{`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place `var string` above the line:

```
$("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
```

And remove `var` from

```
 var string = data.split('|');
```

You can now access `string` in any function you want.

Comment: Still not working :( can you check the changes above?

Comment: What are you doing here..? `var string[3]{` Simply delcare `var string;` Split it when you need, and use `string[3]` the same way you did

Answer (score 0):

You can make it a global variable by adding something like the following at the top of your page:

```
<script>
    var str3 = '';
</script>
```

Set the value of str3 in your first function and then access it in the latter.